# Symfony3 Service container docs error

Tags: php, symfony

Hey all I am playing around with Symfony3, am reading this [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) about service container. Acording to the docs the services are declared in app/config/services.yml like so:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.mailer:
        class:        AppBundle\Mailer
        arguments:    [sendmail]
```

and I can access it in my controller/classes like this:

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmailAction()
    {
        // ...
        $mailer = $this->get('app.mailer');
        var_dump($mailer);die();
//        $mailer->send('ryan@foobar.net', ...);
    }
}
```

I have done exacley that but I get this error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "app.mailer".
```

What could i do wrong in this simple example am I missing something.

I have also noticed that there is another services/yml file under Bundle/Resources/config.srvices.yml. Which one to use when and why...?

Comment: Check the docs again because your sendmail argument is wrong though that by itself is not causing the problem.  I suspect you are running in production mode and perhaps not clearing the cache.  And you are running S3 as opposed to an older version of S2?

Comment: Hey, why would the argument be wrong? either way it should come up with different error in that case, I did clear the cache in my ur I do specyfie localhost:8000/app_dev.php/whatever. Plus the docs say they are 3.1 version.

Comment: Just thought it a bit strange that you want to send the string 'sendmail' as a constructor argument.  But as mentioned, that would not cause this sort of error.  Are you sure you are using spaces and not tabs in the yaml file?  The imports section of config.yml still has services in it?  All very mysterious.  Might try starting a new project and do nothing but create one service and call it from the default controller.

Answer (score 0):

The service `app.mailer` seems to not exists. You should check it by running this command in cli: `bin/console debug:container app.mailer`

> I have also noticed that there is another services/yml file under Bundle/Resources/config.srvices.yml. Which one to use when and why...?

You should use `Bundle/Resources/config/*` only if your bundle will be shared with an other application/open source.
If not, use `app/config/services.yml`.

Comment: for the second part thak you makes sense, but typo in $this...?

Comment: Because the error is `on null` ? Can you share the entire controller ?

Comment: Yep and its says `No services found that match "app.mailer".`

Comment: I don't understand. I just tried with a fresh Symfony 3.1, it's work.